# unity3d OpenGL issue

Tags: opengl, unity3d

When I start unity3d it shows "OpenGL 2.1 (Deprecated)" in the title bar.

running `glxinfo | grep version` shows this:

```
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.3.0 NVIDIA 361.45.11
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.30 NVIDIA via     Cg compiler
OpenGL version string: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 361.45.11
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50
```

...so I have OpenGL 4?

How do I fix the issue with unity3d?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Unity forums](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/opengl-2-1-deprecated.396314/):

> Right now, the rendering backend is forced to OpenGL 2.1, until we work out some remaining issues with OpenGL core in the linux editor.

And:

> Unity has multiple rendering backends, even on the same platform. The OpenGL 2.1 is supposed to be removed in near future, superseded by "glcore", which handles features provided by modern OpenGL versions, like tessellation and compute shaders, thus the deprecated in the name. For now glcore has some serious issues so the editor is fixed to the legacy, but battle tested renderer.
>   So no worries, it doesn't mean there's anything bad with your GPU or driver.

**Update:**
Since version [5.5.0b1](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/#post-2772944), Unity now uses the OpenGL core rendering backend. This means that your development environment must support OpenGL core profile 3.2 or later.

Answer (score 0):

unity3d does not support OpenGL 4, only OpenGL 3.0+. The warning is telling you that you're running an old version of OpenGL that is deprecated, and you should update your drivers.